# R - RandomForest with two Outcome Variables

Tags: r, classification, regression, random-forest

Fairly new to using `randomForest` statistical package here.

I'm trying to run a model with 2 response variables and 7 predictor variables, but I can't seem to because of the lengths of the response variables and/or the nature of fitting the model with 2 response variables.

Let's assume this is my data and model:

```
> table(data$y1)
 0  1  2  3  4 
23 43 75 47 21 

> length(data$y1)
0  4

> table(data$y2)
  0   2   3   4 
104  30  46  29

> length(data$y2)
0  4 

m1<-randomForest(cbind(y1,y2)~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)
```

When I run this model, I receive this error:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  length of response must be the same as predictors
```

I did some troubleshooting, and find that `cbind()` the two response variables simply places their values together, thus doubling the original length, and possible resulting in the above error. As an example,

```
length(cbind(y1,y2))
> 418
t(lapply(data, length()))
>  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   y1   y2
 209 209 209 209 209 209 209  209  209
```

I then tried to solve this issue by running `randomForest` individually on each of the response variables and then apply `combine()` on the regression models, but came across these issues:

```
m2<-randomForest(y1~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)
m3<-randomForest(y2~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)
combine(m2,m3)

Warning message:
In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
```

I then decide to treat the `randomForest` models as classification models, and apply `as.factor()` to both response variables before running `randomForest`, but then came across this new issue:

```
m4<-randomForest(as.factor(y1)~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)
m5<-randomForest(as.factor(y2)~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)
combine(m4,m5)

Error in rf$votes + ifelse(is.na(rflist[[i]]$votes), 0, rflist[[i]]$votes) : 
  non-conformable arrays
```

My guess is that I can't `combine()` classification models.

I hope that my inquiry of trying to run a multivariate Random Forest model makes sense. Let me know if there are further questions. I can also go back and make adjustments.

Comment: When you say two outcome variables do you mean a binary classification, e.g. A vs B, or do you mean response variable one is A vs B and response variable two is C vs D (and essentially predicting four outcomes in total)? Because we can't see your data its a bit tricky.

Comment: @zacdav Good Question. Each response variable has 5 different categories. I hope this answers your question. I'll make the adjustments in the original post.

Comment: In that case you may just be fine by concatenating the two response columns together - something to keep in mind is that is potentially 25 classification outcomes to be predicted and if the number of samples is low you will be unlikely to generate an effective model. 
I don't know if it would be any different but by simply creating two models you can assess the predictive ability of each response independently and then just run two models and again concatenate their outcome for each sample independently. this would achieve what you wanted out of `combine`.

Comment: @zacdav But wouldn't concatenating the response variables place all of the values into one column, and the issue of length of response variables not matching with predictors arise again?

Comment: You would not be using `cbind`, i recommend processing the data beforehand and avoiding doing any manipulating in the randomForest function call. As so, `data[["y3"]] <- paste0(data$y1, data$y2)` and then `randomForest(y3~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your columns outside the randomForest formula:

```
data[["y3"]] <- paste0(data$y1, data$y2)
randomForest(y3~a+b+c+d+e+f+g, data, mtry=7, importance=TRUE)
```

Comment: Just ran the model, and you're right in that the sample size impacted the overall model fit.

Comment: Just had a side question: Doesn't `paste0()` assume that the two variables  are not independent of each other?

Comment: context of the data would indeed provide insight on as to how to guide the appropriate methodology. I don't think that combining them assumes dependence as its not implying any hierarchy between them just that they are discrete when combined. But I am less certain about my answer here. What are you trying to answer with this model.

Comment: Fair response there. Ideally, I want to make a prediction (e.g. compare Y-hat and Y, plot Y-hat against Y, etc.) based the best model, which is assessed using different measures (e.g. MSE, variance explained, etc.). Hope my answer makes sense.

Comment: It is important to understand that what you will get out is essentially a probability that a certain sample belongs to a given categorical outcome (depending on settings the randomForest will just give back the categorical outcome). This is not a regression tree. Your response variables should be coded as factors to make sure the randomForest is not accidentally using regression. You could plot the certainty that each sample has been assigned for its prediction?

Comment: Try using `paste0()` for Multivariate Linear Model using `lm()` and compare it without using `paste0()` - you find that the variance drops greatly in the former condition. And thanks for your last input - I'll take a look at it!